# Dojo - add event listener to dynamically created element

Tags: dom, dojo

Hi I'm trying to add event listener to dynamically created `"<a></a>"` element, but with no success.

Here is the item/element:

```
var item = "<div class='item' id='" + id + "'>"
            + "<div class='cell ion-chevron-right'>"
            + "<span class='cell items'>" + text + "</span>"
            + "<a id='" + id + "_icon' class='mIcon ion-ios-close-outline' style='margin-left:-22px; font-size:18px;'></a>"
            + "</div>"
            + "<div class='cell'>" + price + "</div>"
            + "</div>";

            return item;
          }
```

And here I insert it into the HTML:

```
var addAccessorie = function(id, text, price){
            var m = id + "_accessorie";
            dojo.place(newAccesorieItem(m, text, price)
            ,"maintenance_accessorie"
            ,"after"); // before/after
          }
```

How can I add a CLICK event to the `"<a>"` in ***DOJO***?

Comment: what does newaccesorieItem do? i dont see where you are trying to add either an onClick or an event with dojo.on

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `dojo/dom-construct` to create the `<a>` element and then use `dojo/on` to bind the `onclick` event.

```
var aElement= domConstruct.toDom("<a id='" + id + "_icon' class='mIcon ion-ios-close-outline'
             style='margin-left:-22px; font-size:18px;'></a>");

on(aElement, 'click', function(){
    //Your click handler
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you keep your code exactly as it is,
you can do:

```
    var addAccessorie = function(id, text, price){
        var m = id + "_accessorie";
        dojo.place(newAccesorieItem(m, text, price)
        ,"maintenance_accessorie"
        ,"after"); // before/after

        on(dom.byId(m + '_icon'), 'click', function(){
            //what needs to be done when <a> is clicked
        });
      }
```

Only need to add is a require for `dojo/dom` and `dojo/on`